# How to write this constraint in Gurobipy?

Tags: python, constraints, linear-programming, gurobi

I am writing a linear program using Gurobipy and I am having trouble writing one of the constraints. I am confused about how to sum over the < 0 inequality.

The constraint is as follows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1E5E.jpg

I have already initialized the variables xC and xP (I call this xPone). The parameter B has also already been defined and is contained in a dictionary called B. I refer to m̂ as mone.

This is my current code:

```
m = Model('LP')

m.addConstrs((xC_smp[s,m,p] == - quicksum (B[(s,n,m,p)] * xPone_slnmonep[s,l,n,mone,p]) 
                                       for m in materials for s in sites for l in lines
                                       for n in versions for p in periods for mone in materialones 
                                       if B[(s,n,m,p)] < 0), name='c7')
```

This currently returns an empty set {}. I expect there to be some values in there. I would really appreciate if someone could point out the problem. Thanks.

Comment: From the [`quicksum` docs](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_quicksum.html): "The function takes a list of terms as its argument." So what happens if you wrap the first argument in `[...]`?

Comment: Wrapping the quicksum with [...] also returns an empty set

Comment: Can you post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

This can be work:

```
m.addConstrs( quicksum((xC_smp[s,m,p] for m in materials for s in sites for p in periods))  == 
            - quicksum ((B[(s,n,m,p)] * xPone_slnmonep[s,l,n,mone,p] for m in materials 
                               for s in sites for l in lines for n in versions 
                               for p in periods for mone in materialones 
                                   if B[(s,n,m,p)] < 0), name='c7')
```

Comment: I can't open imgur, hence I didn't see orjinall. You deleted lhs quicksum, this gives error.

Comment: Sorry my last reply might not have made sense. Still learning how to use stackoverflow. Quicksum is not applied to the variable xC[s,m,p]. I tried doing it without the quicksum and although I did not get an error, it has been running for over an hour with no result.

Comment: Using m.write function generate lp file, and check is it ok.

Comment: I dont see how that will help set the constraint

Comment: You will see the open form, and you can control, like debugging.